# how do i print data vertically using loops

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have following problem .
I print data from a table name exam having student_id and marks_obtained for each student_id and. My output is as follow

[image]

but i want the table in different format

```
-----------------------
subject | marks | total
-----------------------
```

toward down side 
as this see output

[image]

but am confused in code please help me 
my CODE IS FOLLOW:

```
$roll=$_POST['roll'];
$exam=$_POST['exam'];
$int1 = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $exam), 10);

$student_info="select student_id,name,father_name,mother_name,roll,class_id,birthday,parent_id from student where roll='$roll'";
$result_student=mysqli_query($link, $student_info) OR trigger_error('login info error');
$data_student= mysqli_fetch_array($result_student,MYSQL_BOTH);


$parent_info="select name from parent where parent_id='$studentparent'";
$result_parent=mysqli_query($link, $parent_info) OR trigger_error('login info error');
$data_parent= mysqli_fetch_array($result_parent,MYSQL_BOTH);

$parentname= $data_parent['name'];

$subject_info="select subject_id,name from subject where class_id='$studentclass'";
$result_subject=mysqli_query($link, $subject_info) OR trigger_error('login info error');
$data_subject= mysqli_fetch_array($result_subject,MYSQL_BOTH);
```

Comment: show us what your php code looks like, what have you already tried?

Comment: What is the table(s) structure? If there's more than 1 table then what are the links between tables. It can be as simple as adding column `subject` to your query and printing it.

Comment: No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: yes there is more then one table ...first table is student,second one is exam ,third one is subject ifetch data differently and now want to print in tables

Comment: there are foreign keys like student have the class_id and student_id ,in subject class_id is primary key and in exam there is student_id,exam_id,subject_id,marks_obtained

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td> Subject </td>
  <td> Marks </td>
  <td> Total </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <?php
 for($i=0;i<count($data);i++){
 ?>
  <td><?php echo $data['subject_name'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['marks'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['total'];?></td>
 <?php
 } 
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sir my data comes from different tables ..plz help me